# Java program- finding if all the values in an array are equal

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, equals

This program will print a statement for when they are all equal, but not when they aren't. What is wrong?

```
int k = 0;
while (k < numbers.length - 1 )
{
    if(numbers[k]==numbers[k+1])
    {
        k++;
    }

}
if(k == numbers.length - 1)
{
    System.out.println("All the numbers are the same");  
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("All the numbers are not the same");  
}
```

Comment: What happens when `numbers[k]` is not equal to `numbers[k+1]`? Or, more specifically, what *doesn't* happen?

Comment: Well, what was expected to happen instead?

Comment: Print the value ok `k` every iteration of the `while` loop. You might discover something there.

Comment: It results in a infinite loop because you are not incrementing the `k` variable if the values are different

Comment: Hint : infinite loops often come from `while` statements. Avoid `while` statement as much as you can. Actually, you can always replace them with `for` statements which are a lot less error prone.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop, see:

```
int[] numbers = {3,3,5,3,3};
int k = 0;
while (k < numbers.length - 1 ) // k never be k >= numbers.length - 1
{ 
    if(numbers[k]==numbers[k+1]) // if not, k never increase
    {
        k++;
    }

}
if(k == numbers.length - 1)
{
    System.out.println("All the numbers are the same");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("All the numbers are not the same");
}
```

You can use following code instead of you solution:

```
private static boolean isEqual(int[] numbers) {
    Integer oldNumber = null;
    for(int number: numbers) {
        if(oldNumber != null && oldNumber != number) {
            return false;
        }
        oldNumber = number;
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {3,3,5,3, 3};


    if(isEqual(numbers))
    {
        System.out.println("All the numbers are the same");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("All the numbers are not the same");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to use a `for` loop, and break out when you find a difference:

```
boolean allSame = true;
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++)
{
    if(numbers[i]!=numbers[i+1])
    {
        allSame = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(allSame)
{
    System.out.println("All the numbers are the same");  
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("All the numbers are not the same");  
}
```

Comment: Actually, the OP can also put all numbers in a `Set` and check that its size is 1...

Comment: Agreed - there are many solutions to this problem - I was just trying to keep it relatively similar to the original code.

Comment: May be, you mean `boolean allSame = true;` instead of `int allSame = true;
`?

Comment: Yes - my brain thought it, but my fingers didn't type it. :)

Comment: No. It works because of the `numbers[i+1]` in the equality check.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
boolean allSame = true;
while (allSame == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[0] != numbers[i+1]) {
            allSame = false;
        }
    }
}

//Lets user know if array contained same elements or not
if (allSame) {
    System.out.println("All the numbers are the same. ");  
}
else {
    System.out.println("Not all numbers are the same. ");  
}
```

Check out the "numbers[0]" in that for loop. We can always compare all the elements to the first element because if they're not the same even once, obviously they're not all the same.

Comment: For the case where the numbers are all the same, you have created an infinite loop.